# MySQL table output in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql

We have this local timesheet and we want to add these two rows together and output its duration (ex: `09:16 am` and `5:35 pm` and we want the output as `8 hrs 51 min`. But we want it in a loop.

[image]

We want to display this in a chart.js in `y` axis for each person. This is what we tried so far and it is not working.

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
var timein = [];
var timeout = [];

for(var i in data) {
    total_duration = (data[i].timein + data[i].timeout);
}

console.log(total_duration);
```

Comment: What error you are getting in this?

Comment: We are getting `Null`.

Comment: Where you are getting null?

Comment: Are you sure that they are `timein` and `timeout` instead of `time_in` and `time_out`?

Comment: @Berkay We also changed that to the database column name but still we are not getting the result.

Comment: @Amy in the console.